# Integer in NSUserDefaults not decreasing

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a strange problem with an integer with NSUserDefaults. In an app I'm developing it's possible to delete some photos. When users are deleting them, an integer in NSUserDefaults decreases (named StorageUsed). This is my code when a user delete a photo:

```
int size = [[json objectForKey:@"size"] intValue];
NSLog(@"photo size: %i",size);
int storageUsed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"StorageUsed"];
storageUsed = storageUsed - size;
NSLog(@"storage used: %i",storageUsed);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:storageUsed forKey:@"StorageUsed"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And this is the output:

```
2012-08-14 12:00:18.285 My Albums[32875:707] photo size: 116769
2012-08-14 12:00:18.293 My Albums[32875:707] storage used: 952516
2012-08-14 12:00:18.514 My Albums[32875:707] photo size: 117333
2012-08-14 12:00:18.516 My Albums[32875:707] storage used: 952516
2012-08-14 12:00:18.729 My Albums[32875:707] photo size: 120303
2012-08-14 12:00:18.731 My Albums[32875:707] storage used: 952516
2012-08-14 12:00:18.991 My Albums[32875:707] photo size: 137845
2012-08-14 12:00:18.993 My Albums[32875:707] storage used: 952516
...
```

As you can see, storage used is not decreasing while size is not zero.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Have you check the value using the `defaults` command?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use that command? It doesn't ring a bell ;)

Comment: `man defaults` should help you.

Comment: Add some further log messages - log the amount you get back from user defaults before you modify it. My guess is that you are resetting this value elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I was resetting it indeed! I'm using AFNetworking for the networking part and I had some code to higher the storage when a user uploads a file to my server. I didn't check there if the user actually uploaded a file, so the storage also increased when a user was deleting a file, which means TotalStorage gets increased and then decreased, which gives the original value. If you place your comment, as an answer, I can accept it if you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried %d instead of %i?

Also, integerForKey: returns a NSInteger, not an int. The difference is
    defined as follow

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: I've tried using %d and changing the int to NSInteger but both solutions didn't work. Thanks for your input however ;)

Comment: If NSInteger - NSInteger doesn't work, then I would check how the original @StorageUsed" is encoded. Was it setInteger:forKey: and did you pass a NSInteger as the first parameter?